# Is range construction possible for the initialization of vector of vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, stdvector

See the below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// Debug Output
void printVV(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vv)
{
    std::for_each(vv.begin(), vv.end(),
        [](std::vector<int>& v) {
            std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(),
                std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
            std::cout << '\n'; });
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    // Initialized with Initializer List
    std::vector<int> v00{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    std::vector<int> v10{ 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 };
    std::vector<int> v20{ 20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29 };
    std::vector<int> v30{ 30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39 };
    std::vector<int> v40{ 40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49 };

    // Fill vector
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v1{ 5,std::vector<int>(v00.begin() + 2,v00.begin() + 5) };
    printVV(v1);

    // Initializer List
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v2{ v00, v10,v20,v30, v40 };
    printVV(v2);

    // Range
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v3{ v2.begin() + 1, v2.begin() + 3 };
    printVV(v3);

    // Subrange init???              ????
    //std::vector<std::vector<int>> v4{ };   ????
    //printVV(v4);

    return 0;
}
```

So, I can initialize a vector of vectors in various ways. All compliant to the given constructor signatures.

The question is now:

**Can we also somehow use the range constructor for initialising the sub vectors also?**

From the signature of the range constructor, it does not seem to be possible, because it expects 2 iterators. So I can initialize only the "outer" vector. What if I want to initialize also the inner vector.

Like for example: 
Build a vector of vector of int and initialize it with `v00.begin()+2, v00.begin()+ 4`, then the next row with `v10.begin(), v10.begin()+ 7` and so on.

Is there any syntax that I am missing or does it simply not work, what I expect?

Comment: Use initializer list: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v4{ {v00.begin()+2,v00.begin()+4}, {v10.begin(),v10.begin()+7} };` ?

Comment: It works. But why? I guess, it is not a range constructor, but an initialzer list. And what's the type of ````{v00.begin() + 2, v00.begin() + 4}```` Is it a ````std::vector<int>````? and if, why? Hm. difficult to understand. Can you please explain more?

Comment: The *outer* vector is created by initializer list - outermost braces `{ ... }`, inside initializer list particular *inner* vectors are constructed by *range constructor* of vector - `vector(IT,IT)`. This `{v10.begin(),v10.begin()+7}` can be replaced by `vector<int>(v10.begin(),v10.begin()+7)`, both constructions in this context mean the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we also somehow use the range constructor for initialising the sub
>   vectors also?

**Yes**. As @rafix07 pointed out in the comments, it is possible via, [initlizer-list constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)<sup>8</sup> of `std::vector`.

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, 
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Since you have *vector of vectors of integers*, the `T` in above `std::initializer_list<T>` would be simply of type `std::vector<int>`(i.e. sub vectors or rows), which could be range-initialised as you have done in `v3` before.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v4
   { {v00.begin() + 2,v00.begin() + 4}, {v10.begin(), v10.begin() + 7}  }; 
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     -> range init of sub vectors(i.e.  std::vector<int>)
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -> initializer list (i.e. std::initializer_list<std::vector<int>>)
```

---

If you don't wanna use `std::initializer_list` constructor, but need to use range construction of sub vectors(each row) of `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, another way is using member function [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert). It has the overload of

```
template< class InputIt >
void insert( iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last);
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

by which, you could insert the sub-vector ranges to the `v4`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v4; 
v4.reserve(2);
v4.insert(v4.end(), v00.begin() + 2, v00.begin() + 4);  // range insertion
v4.insert(v4.end(), v10.begin()    , v10.begin() + 7);  // range insertion
```